# Получение информации с стороннего вэб-ресурса

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите каким образом указать скрипту, что бы он перешёл на какой-либо ресурс, выбрал определённую ссылку на нём (к примеру по id), перешёл по ней, а страниуц, на которую он перешёл вернул мне.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще это [Межсайтовый скриптинг](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межсайтовый_скриптинг), который многие браузеры и сервера блокируют. Поищите в инете множество способов обхода XSS.